# php - inserting multiple variable in an URL for the same parameter

Tags: php, sms

Hi im trying to do a SMS feature for my site. This code works well.

```
https://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?un=xxx&pwd=xxx&dstno=".$number."&msg=".rawurlencode($txt)."&type=1"
```

Although this code doesn't

```
https://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?un=xxx&pwd=xxx&dstno=".$number."&msg=".$msg."%0A".rawurlencode($txt)."&type=1"
```

As you can see in the `&msg=` im trying to send 2 variable but the site tells me there is an error of `MISSING PARAMETER`. How can I properly input that 2 variable for the same parameter?

Comment: Probably a better way to do it but... Couldn't you put $msg . "%0A" . rawurlencode($txt) into one variable before sending it?

Comment: Yeap, that's what I already did. Although, im still curious why it is giving me error

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the code that's actually throwing the error.

Comment: I use that API and all I can say is that is the code itself. both of the variable have value. Im thinking that the second code is outputing a space so it is throwing the `MISSING PARAMETER`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to send a multi line text message with `$msg` on the first line and `$txt` on the second.

As per the [sparse documentation](http://www.isms.com.my/sms_api.php) the end of line character is `%0D` instead of `%0A`.

One other remark: the documenation states that the `msg` parameter must be url encode, so shouldn't you use `rawurlencode($msg)` as well.

So, all in all the code should probably look like:

```
"https://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?
    un=xxx&
    pwd=xxx&
    dstno=".$number."&
    msg=".rawurlencode($msg)."%0D".rawurlencode($txt)."&
    type=1"
```

Note: I've put it on multiple lines for readability only.